# How to remove rows from data frame based on subset function?

Tags: r

I would like to remove some rows from my data frame. I think that using `subset` it will be the easiest way to do that.

I used code below to remove some of the rows before:

```
data_selected <- subset(tbl_data, Name.x != "XXX" & Name.y != "YYY")
```

The question is how to remove the rows from my table which have the same string in two cells (same row).

I think that `mtcars` can be used as an example:

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

`gear` and `carb` columns can be used. As you can see two first rows should be removed from this data because both have the same value `4` in those two columns. Please take to the account that in my data I don't have numeric values but character string.

Comment: Wouldn't `subset(mtcars, gear!=carb)` work

Comment: @akrun 's answer is what you want. Be careful when you deal with non-numeric values as you might have problems comparing factor columns. Try to use : subset(dt, x!=y) on dt = data.frame(x = c("A","B","C"),
                y = c("A","A","B")) and then on dt = data.frame(x = c("A","B","C"),
                y = c("A","A","B"), stringsAsFactors = F)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the information in the post, I think a comparison (`!=`) between the 'gear' and 'carb' columns will be enough to `subset` the dataset

```
df1 <- mtcars[1:5,]
subset(df1, gear!=carb)
#                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

This should also work for 'non-numeric' columns, but not for partial matches.

If we need to make an exception about keeping the rows that have both 'Unknown', we can use the `|` operator after adding another logical condition  (`(gear=='Unknown' & carb=='Unknown')) to the original condition.

Making some changes in the dataset to show the output (just as an example, I know I am changing a numeric column to character by doing this)

```
 df1$gear[4] <- 'Unknown'
 df1$carb[4] <- 'Unknown'
 df1$gear[5] <- 'Unknown'


subset(df1, (gear=='Unknown' & carb=='Unknown') | gear!=carb)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am    gear    carb
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1       4       1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0 Unknown Unknown
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0 Unknown       2
```

Comment: It was too easy! Thanks. Can I ask additional question ? Is it possible to put an exception there ? For example if both columns have a string "Unknown" keep them.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver I have a doubt, suppose if one of the column have 'Unknown' for a row, and the other column it is different.  But, based on our first condition `gear!=carb` we should keep them, right?

Comment: Yes, we keep them. That's the most interesting situation for me! It works pretty well